# How should I "pause" the program to show a tip to the user?

Tags: c#, wpf

When a user is running my program for the first time, I want them to go through a series of tips. Each time they hit a certain "checkpoint", the program will pause what its doing, the background will go a little fuzzy (except for the area of the window the tip is referencing), and a tip will appear on top, explaining how to use it / what to do etc.

I dont quite know what to call this, in my head its called "tutorial tips", but googling anything related to this shows a load of generic tutorials with WPF / C#.

What would be the best way to do this? Am I really just looking at using popups and controling when they are visible? Is there a better / more elegant solution, or any resources out there to aid with this?

Comment: Add two Grids on top of all controls and make one of them black and set the opacity to 0.5. Second Grid to show your tips.

Comment: What do you mean with "pause"? "Modal dialogs" are the usual way to refer to windows that appear on top of everything else and that prevent you from interacting with what's behind them, until you close the dialog (but they do not "freeze" animations or other visual changes or processes that were happening on the windows below, of course)

Comment: @almulo You are right. As far as pausing you could just popup modal message, but I think he wants to make everything fuzzy(dimmed) and show the tip. I guess nicer UI.

Comment: @Dilshod Yup, right, that's a tricky one. Your suggestion could work, but he also wants to keep the area that the tip is referencing, "unfuzzy". So you'd have to look for a way to dim everything else but not that part.

Comment: @almulo I missed that part. I guess you will need to create four different grids to dim your window except the part that Tip if referencing. To do that you will need to figure out the location of the area. And another grid to show your tip.

Comment: Does the highlighted control need to be active during the tip display? It might be easier just to screenshot it and display a static image as part of a single overlaid Canvas/Grid/similar.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to use images for that. You can use a `VisualBrush` to render the same control right on top of itself and the blur/"fuzz" layer.

Comment: Trying to follow the advice here, struggling to switch the VisualBrush between different elements when trying to show differnt tips though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I think I may have dedicated too much time to this, but it sounded like a cool challenge :P

I've created a Decorator class named `TipFocusDecorator` that handles all this.

```
public class TipFocusDecorator : Decorator
{

    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsOpenProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Open.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(TipFocusDecorator), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, IsOpenPropertyChanged));


    public string TipText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TipTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TipTextProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TipText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TipTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TipText", typeof(string), typeof(TipFocusDecorator), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


    public bool HasBeenShown
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasBeenShownProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasBeenShownProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HasBeenShown.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasBeenShownProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HasBeenShown", typeof(bool), typeof(TipFocusDecorator), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    private static void IsOpenPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var decorator = sender as TipFocusDecorator;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            if (!decorator.HasBeenShown)
                decorator.HasBeenShown = true;

            decorator.Open();
        }

        if (!(bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            decorator.Close();
        }
    }

    TipFocusAdorner adorner;

    protected void Open()
    {
        adorner = new TipFocusAdorner(this.Child);
        var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this.Child);
        adornerLayer.Add(adorner);

        MessageBox.Show(TipText);  // Change for your custom tip Window
        IsOpen = false;
    }

    protected void Close()
    {
        var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this.Child);
        adornerLayer.Remove(adorner);
        adorner = null;
    }

}
```

This Decorator must be used in XAML around the control you want to focus. It has three properties: `IsOpen`, `TipText` and `HasBeenShown`. `IsOpen` must be set to `true` to make the focus and tip window appear (and is set to `false` automatically when the tip window is closed). `TipText` allows you to define the text that must be shown in the tip window. And `HasBeenShown` keeps track of whether the tip window has been shown, so it only shows once. You can use Bindings for all these properties or set them from code-behind.

To create the focus effect, this class uses another custom Adorner, the `TipFocusAdorner`:

```
public class TipFocusAdorner : Adorner
{
    public TipFocusAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        var root = Window.GetWindow(this);
        var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(AdornedElement);
        var presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(adornerLayer);
        Matrix transformToDevice = presentationSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;

        var sizeInPixels = transformToDevice.Transform((Vector)adornerLayer.RenderSize);
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(sizeInPixels.X), (int)(sizeInPixels.Y), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

        var oldEffect = root.Effect;
        var oldVisibility = AdornedElement.Visibility;
        root.Effect = new BlurEffect();
        AdornedElement.SetCurrentValue(FrameworkElement.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Hidden);
        rtb.Render(root);
        AdornedElement.SetCurrentValue(FrameworkElement.VisibilityProperty, oldVisibility);
        root.Effect = oldEffect;

        drawingContext.DrawImage(rtb, adornerLayer.TransformToVisual(AdornedElement).TransformBounds(new Rect(adornerLayer.RenderSize)));
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(22, 0, 0, 0)), null, adornerLayer.TransformToVisual(AdornedElement).TransformBounds(new Rect(adornerLayer.RenderSize)));
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(AdornedElement) { AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left, TileMode = TileMode.None, Stretch = Stretch.None },
            null,
            AdornedElement.RenderTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(AdornedElement.RenderSize)));
    }
}
```

This dims and blurs (and freezes, since it actually uses a screen capture) all the window, while keeping the desired controls focused and clear (and moving - i.e. in TextBoxes, the text input caret will still be visible and blinking).

To use this Decorator, you only must set it like this in XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:TipFocusDecorator x:Name="LoginDecorator" 
                             TipText="Enter your username and password and click 'Login'"
                             IsOpen="{Binding ShowLoginTip}">
        <local:LoginForm />
    </local:TipFocusDecorator>
</StackPanel>
```

And the final result, when `ShowLoginTip` is set to `true`:

[image]

**KNOWN ISSUES**

Right now this uses a simple `MessageBox` to show the tip, but you can create your own `Window` class for the tips, style it as you want, and call it with `ShowDialog()` instead of the `MessageBox.Show()` (and you could also control where the `Window` appears, if you want it to appear right next to the focused Control or something like that).

Also, this won't work inside UserControls right away, because `AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(AdornedElement)` will return `null` inside UserControls. This could be easily fixed by looking for the `AdornerLayer` of the PARENT of the `UserControl` (or the parent of the parent, recursively). There are functions around to do so.

This won't work for Pages either, only for Windows. Simply because I use `Window.GetWindow(this)` to get the parent `Window` of the Decorator... You could use other functions to get the parent, that could work either with Windows, Pages or whatever. As with the `AdornerLayer` problem, there are plenty of solutions for this around here.

Also, I guess this could be animated somehow (making the blur and dim effect appear gradually, for instance), but haven't really looked into it...

Comment: Hey, this looks really impressive! I just implemented it whilst trying to change as little as possible to see it working, but cant get it to happen. Everything compiles fine ETC, but changing ShowLoginTip to true does nothing. I have a button, and in that command I have 
            ShowLoginTip = true;
            OnPropertyChanged("ShowLoginTip");
tried with and without OnPropertyChanged, neither get it to happen.

Comment: Mmmh... I just tried with a button, and it worked. Make sure your Binding's working (check the Output tab in VS). Or simply debug my code, it may be crashing or failing at some point (maybe you're using UserControls, in which case it won't work - Look at the "known issues" part)

Comment: in XAML, i have an <image> inside the decorator, IsOpen bound to ShowLoginTip. In ViewModel, I have public bool ShowLoginTip = false; and in the buttons command, it sets this to true successfully. When it is set to true, no other code is run, it doesnt activate the decorator stuff at all.

Comment: Rookie mistake - was using showLogintip as a var not as a property.

This is an amazing answer - Thankyou so much! ^_^

Comment: Hey @NahuelIanni !! Nice to see you around! ;)

Comment: Made some corrections and improvements to the Adorner: the last line said `DesiredSize` when it should be `RenderSize`, and added extra code to prevent the focused elements to have a blurry counterpart under them - this way they show up more sharply (and TextBlocks are more readable).

Comment: Amazing! Just tried wrapping some more complex stuff in this and hit problems. Came here and you had already solved them! (I think it was the Rendersize part). Again, thankyou so much! Definitely reusing this again in the future. :)

Comment: Added example of my own usage of this, along with custom window with a few extra frills :) Hope thats OK :)

Comment: Not a major problem, but if you wrap this around a grid with no border, the positioning of the grid is off. For now, I have to set my grid's backgrounds to the colour of what is behind them. Not major, but not something you may want to so if using the background of something behind normally.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's because of the `VisualBrush` behavior... It seems to ignore the contents of the Visuals that have no Background. But if you set `Background="Transparent"` it may work ok. Are you using `Padding`, maybe? Because with `Margin` it should work fine, but a border-less background-less `Grid` with `Padding` is probably problematic indeed.

Comment: Yes, applying transparent BG now. :) Thanks. I am however having trouble with content within tabcontrol... If the current selected tab is where the adorner lies the popup works, but the rendering messes up underneath. If a different tab is selected, then it fuzzes things out but doesnt popup a window. (Even if I change the tab just beforehand). Also, the blur effect remains within the tabcontrol, and doesnt apply to the whole window.

Comment: Mmmh, yeah, that's something I thought could happen... I'll try and edit with some more improvements (including some from your edit!) today, or on monday if I'm unable today.

Comment: Thankyou, that would be awesome :)

Comment: Hey, any news on this working inside Tab Controls? Heres an example of what it looks like in a tab control. http://i.imgur.com/eshxSwp.jpg
The decorator is around the text reading GP: 507. The blur only applies inside the tab, instead of the whole window and the background of the tab looks like it replicated the tab control a few times.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your tip as a window and show it using `ShowDialog()`.  This gives you a Modal dialog, as others have suggested.  Be sure to set it's owner. Just before you show it, you can use

```
<UIElement.Effect>
    <BlurEffect/>
</UIelement.Effect>
```

to set your window or outer container's(grid maybe) Blur Effect.  The radius property sets the "level" of blur, so I imagine you can set it to 0 initially and modify it programatically when you show your dialog