# How to recursively select the parent of AdornedElement when returning null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, decorator, adorner

OK, so an answer I previously recieved [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695033/how-should-i-pause-the-program-to-show-a-tip-to-the-user/31704374?noredirect=1#comment51373719_31704374), works really great. In the known issues however, it mentions the following:

> Also, this won't work inside UserControls right away, because
>   `AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(AdornedElement)` will return `null`
>   inside UserControls. This could be easily fixed by looking for the
>   `AdornerLayer` of the PARENT of the `UserControl` (or the parent of
>   the parent, recursively). There are functions around to do so.

So, I am using the code great for the most part, however I hit a problem when I try and use this on an element within a tabcontrol.Instead of having the desired effect, the blur effect only applies within the TabItem, instead of the whole window. Additionally, the content of the tabItem seems to be printed out a few times as a visual brush of sorts. Here is an example. The Custom Decorator is wrapped around a stackpanel containing 2 textblocks, one containing "GP: " and the other containing a number. Here is the before and after shots of what it looks like when this is applied within a tab item:

[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

So, How would I correct this?

I will post my code snippets here, as I have slightly modified them since the answer (though not in a way that has "broken" this)

Here is the XAML, with the decorator:

```
<models:TipFocusDecorator IsOpen="{Binding TutorialBoolGP}" TipHead="{Binding TutorialTitle}" TipText="{Binding TutorialDescription}" TipPos="{Binding TutorialPosition}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock Text="GP: " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayerGP, Converter={StaticResource IntToComma}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</models:TipFocusDecorator>
```

The decorator:

```
public class TipFocusDecorator : Decorator
{

    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsOpenProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Open.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(TipFocusDecorator),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, IsOpenPropertyChanged));


    public string TipText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TipTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TipTextProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TipText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TipTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TipText", typeof(string), typeof(TipFocusDecorator), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


    public string TipHead
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TipHeadProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TipHeadProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TipText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TipHeadProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TipHead", typeof(string), typeof(TipFocusDecorator), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


    public string TipPos
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TipPosProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TipPosProperty, value); }
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TipPos.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TipPosProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TipPos", typeof(string), typeof(TipFocusDecorator), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


    public bool HasBeenShown
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasBeenShownProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasBeenShownProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HasBeenShown.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasBeenShownProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HasBeenShown", typeof(bool), typeof(TipFocusDecorator), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    private static void IsOpenPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var decorator = sender as TipFocusDecorator;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            if (!decorator.HasBeenShown)
                decorator.HasBeenShown = true;

            decorator.Open();
        }

        if (!(bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            decorator.Close();
        }
    }

    TipFocusAdorner adorner;

    protected void Open()
    {
        adorner = new TipFocusAdorner(this.Child);
        var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this.Child);
        adornerLayer.Add(adorner);
        TutorialTip tip = new TutorialTip(TipHead,TipText,TipPos);
        tip.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        double width = tip.Width;
        double height = tip.Height;
        Point position = this.Child.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d));
        switch (TipPos)
        {
            case "Bottom":
                position.X += (this.Child.RenderSize.Width / 2) - (width / 2);
                position.Y += this.Child.RenderSize.Height + 10;
                break;
            case "Top":
                position.X += (this.Child.RenderSize.Width / 2) - (width / 2);
                position.Y += -height - 10;
                break;
            case "Left":
                position.X += -width - 10;
                position.Y += (this.Child.RenderSize.Height / 2) - (height / 2);
                break;
            case "Right":
                position.X += this.Child.RenderSize.Width + 10;
                position.Y += (this.Child.RenderSize.Height / 2) - (height / 2);
                break;
        }
        tip.Left = position.X;
        tip.Top = position.Y;
        tip.ShowDialog();
        //MessageBox.Show(TipText + position);  // Change for your custom tip Window
        IsOpen = false;
    }

    protected void Close()
    {
        var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this.Child);
        adornerLayer.Remove(adorner);
        adorner = null;
    }

}
```

And finally the Adorner:

```
public class TipFocusAdorner : Adorner
{
    public TipFocusAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        var root = Window.GetWindow(this);
        var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(AdornedElement);
        var presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(adornerLayer);
        Matrix transformToDevice = presentationSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;

        var sizeInPixels = transformToDevice.Transform((Vector)adornerLayer.RenderSize);
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(sizeInPixels.X), (int)(sizeInPixels.Y), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

        var oldEffect = root.Effect;
        var oldVisibility = AdornedElement.Visibility;
        root.Effect = new BlurEffect();
        AdornedElement.SetCurrentValue(FrameworkElement.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Hidden);
        rtb.Render(root);
        AdornedElement.SetCurrentValue(FrameworkElement.VisibilityProperty, oldVisibility);
        root.Effect = oldEffect;

        drawingContext.DrawImage(rtb, adornerLayer.TransformToVisual(AdornedElement).TransformBounds(new Rect(adornerLayer.RenderSize)));
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(22, 0, 0, 0)), null, adornerLayer.TransformToVisual(AdornedElement).TransformBounds(new Rect(adornerLayer.RenderSize)));
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(AdornedElement) { AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left, TileMode = TileMode.None, Stretch = Stretch.None },
            null,
            AdornedElement.RenderTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(AdornedElement.RenderSize)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer retrieves an adorner layer above (parent) of a given element. So it's not necessarily true that this will return null inside a UserControl. As long as there exists an AdornerLayer above the UserControl, it will return that. Window by default creates an AdornerLayer, but only after it's loaded. 
In fact I tested your code using a simple

```
<Grid x:Name="Container">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">Outside of Tab</TextBlock>
        <TabControl x:Name="TabControl">
            <TabItem Header="Here">
                <local:UserControlContainingTipFocus/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

I could not reproduce the problem. The blur is applied to everything inside the window

So in your case, there must be a parent of the UserControl that created an AdornerLayer. I'm guessing the TabControl or TabItem. You can use [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to check.

But not to worry, you can create your own AdornerLayer. Simply put the element you want to blur inside an AdornerDecorator.

```
<Window >
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <Grid x:Name="Container">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">Outside of adorner</TextBlock>
                    <TabControl x:Name="TabControl">
                        <TabItem Header="Here">
                            <local:TestControl></local:TestControl>
                        </TabItem>
                    </TabControl>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</Window>
```

Then modify every call to AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer. Instead of passing the original element, pass the container you want to blur. In my example it's either the Grid, or the AdornerDecorator itself.

```
var root = Window.GetWindow(this);
var blurContainer = (Visual) root.Content;
var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(blurContainer);
```

The code above uses Window.GetWindow and access it's content (first child). But you can easily create a property in TipFocusAdorner/Decorator to specify which element to pass to AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer

Comment: Thanks, using the code you put up I was able to modify both adorner and decorator to get this to work perfectly - Thankyou! :)